# one long seamless pdf with multiple artboards - illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, artboard

Wondering if there's anyway in Illustrator that it's possible to make one long seamless pdf (1 page) from multiple artboards with different height?
e.g.:there are 11 artboards, 1 just want to create 1page seamless pdf instead of a pdf with 11pages. Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a single artboard which encompasses all your other artboards, then save that new artboard as a PDF.

(Artboards in Illustrator can overlap one another)